# Calling a function outside main

Tags: python

I'm calling a function outside main, like below, and running into name error. Is there a way to resolve this error without moving the function call `getdata()` inside main?

```
filename="data_file.txt"
AU=getdata(filename)

def getdata(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    return file.read()

def main():

NameError: name 'getdata' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to put a `pass` under `main()`, by the way; can't just leave it empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a `main()` function at all; happens though that, in your code, the definition of `getdata()` has not been reached before the function call.

Try the following:

```
def getdata(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    return file.read()

filename="data_file.txt"
AU=getdata(filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only call a function *after* it is defined. Move the `AU` line *after* defining `getdata()`:

```
def getdata(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    return file.read()

AU = getdata(filename)
```